# Payment card validation with issue number and start date

Tags: algorithm, payment, credit-card

I'm aware of the Luhn algorithm for validation of payment card numbers.

However, is there something similar that will tell me whether a particular card requires a start date or issue number, as these aren't universal?

Using this information, I would then show or hide the start date and/or issue number input boxes once a customer has entered their payment card number.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no there is no way to detect whether the expiry date (I assume that's what you meant by `start date`) is required based on the card number.

In these kind of situations (i.e. special cases for different cards), I've turned to this [site](https://www.binlist.net) as well as the backing [data](https://github.com/binlist/data). With this data, you can get the bin of a credit card from the first 6-8 digits. I'm skeptical as to whether even the bin contains the data you are looking for, but good luck!

Just a note: be wary of the data since it is open source. In my experience it has been accurate, but make sure you keep that in mind. There are enterprise solutions to get bin data if accuracy is that important to you.

Comment: No, I don't mean expiry date: Start date is essentially the issue date of the card. As this field is only present on a small minority of cards (in the UK at least), some customers get confused and fill the fields in when they are not required for their card, resulting in a payment rejection. A similar field is the issue number, which customers sometimes confuse with CV2 (which it is not).

Comment: Ah, I see why it didn't make complete sense to me; I don't think issue dates/numbers are common in North America. But as far as I know, given a card number all you can find is the card's bin. Have you checked what one of these cards' bin looks like? It might give you a clue as to whether the issue date/number exist for that card.